# Grails 3.0 support in NetBeans

Tags: grails, netbeans, grails-3.0

I was running Grails 2.2.0 in NetBeans and it was working fine. I tried to upgrade the project to Grails 3.0 but after creating the project NetBeans is not able to open the project.

Does anyone know which plugins to install in NetBeans (if available) to make Grails 3.0 work?

Comment: Also having issues with grails 3.0 + netbeans, fresh install of everything, cannot create new projects, I guess i have to revert back to 2.2 also.

Comment: as with all the other tooling, that might already be aware of grails3: have you tried to import/create this as an gradle project?

Comment: I have tried to create the project and then open it as gradle project. But the structure is not what we expect from grails project. I have someone from netbeans team reply my tweet saying something like it grails 3.0 was just released so the support is not available.

Comment: Grails aware artifacts are not yet available in Netbeans. However, you should be able to open and run this project from Netbeans. To create the project, you will still need command line tools.

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to let you know that I've added initial support for grails 3 in NetBeans.

https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=254405

At the moment you can get these with the latest NetBeans nightly: http://bits.netbeans.org/download/trunk/nightly/latest/

This will allow NetBeans to recognise/create projects, and the create controller/domain/etc actions working.

One important thing still missing is adding support for the gradle build files (no syntax highlighting or helpers for the gradle files), but in the meantime you may try it and report problems/improvements.